# Replace \n\n with \n\t in Google Docs

Tags: regex, replace, google-docs

I would like to replace two carriage returns (\n\n) with a carriage return and a tab (\n\t) in Google Docs (regular document NOT a spreadsheet). If I enter \n\t in replace with the simple text, as typed, is inserted, not the nonprinting characters. Is this a Google Doc limitation or is there a way to get around it?

Comment: can you add an example of your input text ?

Comment: \n\n in replace and \n\t in replace with. The pattern is found, yet the replacement is \n\t as text instead of the breakline and lead space at the beginning of the next line as expected

Comment: Do you mean you are inside an open Google Document, and are using the Search and Replace dialog (Ctrl+H)?

Comment: Yes! That's it...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from inside the Google Docs UI; it doesn't provide a way to specify the actual newline and tab characters for replacement.

Comment: That's so inconvenient. Anyone who lands here please follow the advice in https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8197972?hl=en&msgid=8201646 to use "**Help > Help Doc Improve**" to send them feedback that _we need to get the replace function to accept the special character as a replacement, e.g. \n\t as newline and tab characters for replacement when the RE match is turned on_.

Answer (score 0):

You can by

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> then `\n+` (46hex code) for search

OR

- search `\n\s` - replace with whatever you want

Comment: The question specified searching for for \n\n not \n\s. The question was asking how to replace with \n\t and this is not currently supported. As the question states, Google Docs replaces with the actual characters "\n\t" and not a newline and a tab. Your answer does not address the question and your suggested solution does not work.